# SQLAlchemy fails to insert timestamp into MSSQL

Tags: python, sql-server, datetime, sqlalchemy, luigi

> sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (pyodbc.IntegrityError) ('23000',
>   '[23000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Cannot insert  an explicit value into a
>   timestamp column. Use INSERT with a column list to exclude the
>   timestamp column, or insert a D EFAULT into the timestamp column.
>   (273) (SQLExecDirectW)') [SQL: 'INSERT INTO task_events (task_id,
>   event_name, ts) OUTP UT inserted.id VALUES (?, ?, ?)'] [parameters:
>   (54, 'RUNNING', datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 16, 18, 5, 55, 595066))]

The error seems to be related to this:

`You can't insert explicit values into a timestamp column.
Timestamp values are unique binary numbers that are automatically generated.`

Isn't SQLAlchemy aware of that? Is there some key\setting to let SQLAlchemy know to now insert timestamps?

[This](https://github.com/spotify/luigi/blob/master/luigi/db_task_history.py) seems to be the luigi code that handles SQLAlchemy.

ps. There problem here is that luigi is using SQLAlchemy, and I don't want to modify luigi's code, but if you could propose an easy solution on luigi side, that would work also.

Comment: Hi, could you please post the code snippet that causes this. In general, SqlAlchemy is able to do fine-grained inserts on only some columns, but a solution here would depend on how your luigi code interacts with sqlalchemy, or modifying the database schema to allow insertion into the `ts` column

Comment: Try using [`FetchedValue`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/defaults.html#triggered-columns). Without a complete and verifiable example it is hard to say more. What's providing that datetime value to insert?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server's `timestamp` data type is not, actually, a timestamp - it is more of a sequence (it is an ancient holdover, and horribly misnamed). If you need to update a date time value, use a `datetime` data type. If date only, use a `date` data type (depending on your edition of MSSQL.) Looking at your code, you probably want to use a [`datetime2` data type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx), e.g. `DECLARE @dt2 datetime2(7)`

Comment: @LaughingVergil just like I said, I don't want to touch luigi code, if possible

Comment: I think @LaughingVergil is suggesting you change the database schema, rather than touch luigi code, again it would be easier to suggest solutions if a complete example were provided.

Comment: I'm afraid that there is no way around it if the table being created is created with a `timestamp` data type. Understand that these fields are inherently not updateable in SQL Server, and there is no trick workaround. Your best bet would be to change the data type of that column on the destination table to `datetime2(7)` or `datetime`, since what the code *intends* is to log a specific date and time. Just for emphasis, *there is no workaround that allows code to update a timestamp field in SQL Server - it is autogenerated only.*

Comment: @HaleemurAli @LaughinhVergil well, its not possible to alter timestamp column, it appers... if I modify `ts = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.TIMESTAMP, index=True, nullable=False)` to `ts = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.DateTime, index=True, nullable=False)` nothing changes? O_o

Comment: after the table is created, changing the definition has no effect, i.e. sqlalchemy will not introspect the database schema and automatically update it to reflect the current specified model. you could implement `alembic` for database migrations, or delete the table on the database & let sqlalchemy create a fresh version with `DateTime`, or change the sqlalchemy model & alter the table manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, thanks to these fine gentleman out there @LaugingVergil and @HaleemurAli I've just decided to add another `sed` hack to my dockerfile...

I just do `RUN sed -i 's/TIMESTAMP/DateTime/g' /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/luigi/db_task_history.py` before `CMD /usr/bin/luigid`